# How to make a web page specificly accessible?

Tags: paypal, download

so i want to make a website where i'm going to sell a specific software and after the user completes the paypal checkout he is going to be redirected to the download page. My question is how do i make that page accessible only after the checkout? If you generaly have a better way to successfuly deliver the software is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Auto Return feature to reach this requirement. Please refer to the link below for the details.

https://www.paypal.com/az/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside